# PHP dynamic grid to display news wont reset id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building my new blog with wordpress and want to create a grid which holds my latest posts, users will then be able to click the nodes and be redirected to that specific posts.

What I want to do is to create x amount of nodes per row, these nodes are then assigned a class of node and node$x to apply specific styling (I want some nodes to be wider than others)

The problem I am having is my `$id` does not reset once it exceeds a set value

The function is invoked when this condition is called -

```
    <div class="row span12 news-tiles-inner">
        <?php $node_id = 1; ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
            <?php 
                create_node( $node_id );
                $node_id+= 1;
             ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
```

The `create_node()` function looks like this

```
function create_node( $id ) {   
    if($id > 3) {
        $id = 1;
    }
    $content = get_the_title();
    echo "<div class='node node$id'>
                    <a href='#'>$content</a>

          </div>";

    return $id;
```

}

In its current state my node id's output as node1, node2, node3 but then the value of the remaining nodes are instantiated to node1, node1, node1 for my remaining nodes in the query, I am relatively new to PHP so I may be missing something simple, any help would be much appreciated

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are reseting the local counter variable from the `create_node` function, and not the counter from your loop (you are only incrementing it). So after it reaches 4 your function will continue to reset the local counter to 1.

Just move the reset logic in your loop instead:

```
<?php 

    if($node_id++ > 3) {   // if it's 4, reset it to 1
        $node_id = 1;
    }

   create_node( $node_id );
?>
```